# access java synchronized method from native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, synchronized

I have a java class that has some (private static) synchronized methods which I want to call from native code as well. with some example code it becomes more clear what I mean

```
public class SomeClass {
   private static synchronized void method() {
     //do something that needs synchronization
   }
}
```

and the associated native code (C++)

```
void someFunction(JNIEnv * env) {
   jclass someClass = env->findClass("SomeClass");
   jmethodID methodId = env->GetStaticMethodID(jclass, "method", "()V");
   env->MonitorEnter(jclass); // <--- IS THIS NEEDED/ALLOWED
   env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jclass, methodId);
   env->MonitorExit(jclass); // <--- IS THIS NEEDED/ALLOWED
}
```

So what I am wondering is if I need to call MonitorEnter/MonitorExit, or if the method synchronization is enforced already by the synchronized attribute on SomeClass.method().
I am not so much interested in rewriting the code. I can think of a few solutions to work around this, but I am interested in what the behaviour is, given a synchronized method that is called from native code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Section [8.4.3.6 synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6) of the Java Language Specification says that declaring the method synchronized has the same effect as adding a synchronized block within the method.

Comment: Thank you! Given that these are specified to have the same effect, I will assume that they do generate the same byte code, so the MonitorEnter/MonitorExit are not needed/redundant here.

Answer (score 3):

No, explicit `MonitorEnter` / `MonitorExit` are not needed. According to [The JNI guide](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html),

> ...it is preferable to express synchronization constructs in the Java programming language. If, for example, a static native method needs to enter the monitor associated with its defining class, you should define a static synchronized native method as opposed to performing JNI-level monitor synchronization in native code.

Even though your case of calling a Java method from the native code (and not vice versa) isn't directly discussed in the spec, the opposite is not stated either, so I would *assume* that it works similarly.

Comment: Thanks. I had found this information before, but as this is the opposite direction I am not so sure. If the synchronized method is compiled into something similar as method() { synchronized(this) { method body} } I'd expect no problems either. I'm just not sure what byte code is generated for this, and what the entry point for the jni call is exactly.

Comment: @Eric Moors: To be absolutely sure that it's the same byte code, there's no other way than to inspect the byte code. But I would almost bet that it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you own `SomeClass` you can just do

```
public class SomeClass {
private static synchronized void method() {
     //do something that needs synchronization
   }

private static void synchronizedMethod() {
     method();
   }
}
```

and just call `synchronizedMethod()` from C++.

Comment: Sure, that's one of the alternatives. Like I said though, I'm not so much interested in rewriting the code. I'd like to understand what is going on.